# Calling a function by name that is not part of the global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have something like this :

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.feature = (function($){
  var somelocalVariable,
      otherone

  init = function() {
  },
  somePrivateFunction = function() {
    var functionName = 'otherFunction';
    //how can I call otherFunction by name (using variable above)
  }, 
  otherFunction = function() {

  };

  return {
    init: init
  }

})(jQuery);
```

In this example if I do `window['otherFunction']` nothing will happen because its not a global function. How can I execute it as a part of the more private scope?

Comment: That doesn’t even make sense. `MyApp.feature` becomes `otherFunction` and `{ init: init }` is discarded. Anyways, put your functions in an object if you want to refer to them by name.

Comment: @minitech—I think the OP intended to return an object with properties, not just *otherFunction*.

Comment: Your mismatching your function declarations too.

Comment: Not sure what is going on in that code since it is weird, but Did you think about trying `this[functionName]` ????

Comment: `var functionName = otherFunction` without quote

Comment: Now you have a bunch of implicitly global variables, and `window['otherFunction']` should work fine. (Tip: use function declaration style and don’t make multiple declarations per `var`. Also, turn on strict mode.)

Comment: @epascarello exactly what I've been looking for, can you please post an answer I'll accept. I was trying self, victim of multiple languages I guess. Thank you, sorry about sloppy question statement

Comment: @minitech thank you for your observation, I never realized I forgot a comma before my init function declarations, hence polluting the global scope. Added comma, now those functions are not available globally, only if exposed i.e init function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "window" with "this"

```
this[functionName]();
```